# Retrieve selected text from select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS 2 (with [this](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) template) and below is what I've done so far:

```
<template>
     <select id="dropDown" v-model="mytrack">
           <option value="">Select track</option>
           <option v-for="track in tracksList" :value="track.circuitId">{{ track.name }}</option>
     </select>
     <button type="submit" @click="retrieveByTrack(track.circuitId)">
                                Search
     </button>
</template>

<script>  
    export default {
                data() {

                    return {
                        tracksList: []
                    };
                },
                created: {
                     // here I fill tracksList[] with a list of tracks
                },
                methods: {
                  retrieveByTrack(trackId){
                   }
                }
        }
</script>
```

I want to be able to select an option from the select element and when I click the submit button I should call `retrieveByTrack(track.circuitId)` method passing the option value selected in the select element.

Comment: why not retrieving the selected value later inside the called function.

Answer (score 1):

Simple like that.
I created fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/npw7fgta/

```
<div class='col-xs-12'>
<hr/>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ $data |json }}</pre>
  <select v-model='result'> <option v-for="task in tasks" :value="task.id">{{ task.name }} </option> </select>
</div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {

    tasks: [
    { id: 0 , name: 'First task'},
    { id: 5, name: 'fifth task'}
    ]

  }
});
```

Then you have task/track.id available in `result` so you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @M U it seems that this doesn't work if html content is wrapped inside <template> tags

Comment: are you using single file components & webpack ?

Comment: so you have to put `return { } ` in data, instead of just object type

Comment: yes, I fill tracksList[] in created hook as soon as my component is loaded and then return it

Comment: it has to work. Can you create quick Webpack bin with your code? I will help you